# Execute every 3 seconds cron job PHP script

Tags: php, cron

```
<?php
$banlog = file("bans.txt");
foreach($banlog as $ip) {
    exec("iptables -I INPUT -s $ip -j DROP");
}
$fp = fopen("bans.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp,"");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

With .htaccess I don't like how users only get the access denied when they are "deny from $ip"

I like using iptables but I don't want to login my server everytime to block someone from connecting.  So my php script above I want to execute it every 3 seconds instead of the limited 1 minute cron tab. To do so I need to create a controlled loop to execute every 3 seconds, 20 times.

What would the best way to do this? My script runs in milliseconds.

Comment: Running `iptables` every three seconds sounds like a *terrible* idea that will put a lot of strain on the server. Why do you need this? Why does it need this kind of resolution?

Comment: When you ban someone with IPtables it shows the server as being offline. Completely blocking them out of access. I wish .htaccess did that but it does not.  Do you know any alternative?

Comment: You could lose data here.  Another process could write to bans.txt while this process is in the foreach loop, and then the new data would get summarily erased with your fwrite.

Comment: Why do you need to block people from the whole server with a "connection timed out"? At least use `REJECT` instead of `DROP`...

Comment: I was hoping 3 seconds would be a fast enough time to complete everything before that happened ^

Comment: @Kyle Running it every three seconds makes it *more* likely that you'll have data loss. You need to obtain a lock on the file before you truncate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive from Apache's mod_rewrite (RewriteModule) to achieve a dynamic file based IP blacklisting/white listing.

Examples here:

https://wiki.koumbit.net/ApacheBlacklisting

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/283

Using your cron, just update the blacklist text file. No need to call iptable. 
(Please note, you DO NOT need to restart Apache for using RewriteMap based black/white listing)

Comment: This is probably the cleanest and most sane way to go. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Reading a file with potentially hundreds or thousands of lines and running an iptable command on every one of them *every three seconds* is *insane* - it's bound to put unbearable strain on your server, and cause unpredictable behaviour if two of the three-second jobs interfere with each other while reading the file.

Why not call `iptables` once every time you actually add something to the `bans.txt` file?

Comment: This was my original intention but I have not found a way to successfully use the PHP exec() function inside my admin control panel. It only ever works if I'm logged in the server.  How can I call Iptables from PHP without having to login? When I attempt to, nothing happens.

Comment: @Kyle you mean, you can only trigger it from SSH when logged in as the admin user?

Comment: @Kyle Are you specifying the full path to `iptables`?

Comment: yes.  When I try to do something like this http://pastebin.com/eLZHaAAH nothing shows ip in iptables.  And I even tried http://pastebin.com/6KJjtLxk and still nothing appears.  What is wrong?

@meagar I don't believe so.  What is the full path?

Comment: @Kyle this is to be expected because the user PHP runs as probably has no right to change iptables rules. I would go with @Sarwar's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should come at this from a different direction - why are they being banned? Is there something like fail2ban you should be using instead?

However, this is also bad - anyone visiting your site from behind a company firewall will all share the same IP, so you'll be banning an entire company not just an individual.

Solution 1;
Your code has a race condition where two threads could read and write to the same file simultaneously, which would be bad since it could corrupt your IPTABLES setup. If you insist on doing this, exclusive-lock the the bans.txt file before processing the entries.

```
$banlogFp = fopen("bans.txt","a+"); // open for r+w
$tnow = time();
//loop until have lock, or 2 seconds elapsed 
//(since will be invoked again after 3 sec)
while (!flock("bans.txt") && (time() - $tnow < 2) {
   $banlogTxt = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
   $banlogTxt = preg_replace('/\.\\r\\n/m', '@\n', $s); //any CRLF to LF 
   $banlog = explode("\n", $banlogTxt); //Convert to array, splittng on LF
   foreach($banlog as $ip) {
       //validate $ip is numeric - don't want malicious hacker to break IPTABLES
       if (preg_match("/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/",$ip+)) {
           exec("iptables -I INPUT -s $ip -j DROP");
       }
   }
   ftruncate($banlogFp, 0); 
   fclose($banlogFp);
}
```

Solution 2;
You don't need to use the "Deny from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" command in .htaccess, instead you can use a rewrite rule to point them to any page of your choosing. Much safer than modifying IPTABLES, but still has the big-stick problem of banning other individuals sharing the IP address. E.g.

```
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 192.12.131.1 REDIR="redir"
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 192.12.131.2 REDIR="redir"
SetEnvIf REMOTE_ADDR 192.12.131.3 REDIR="redir"
RewriteCond %{REDIR} redir
RewriteRule ^/$ /you_are_banned.html
```

Solution 3 (best!);
Don't allow anyone to post to your site unless they've registered a username + password, then just ban the username, not the IP address. Use a database like MySQL to store users and passwords, and a flag to say if they're banned.

Comment: Thanks.  I like the flock for protecting corruption.